# How can I uppercase a MultivaluedMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a MultivaluedMap object and I want to convert all the keys (not the values) to uppercase.

I managed to iterate through the object, but I can't figure out how to reload it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you just need to uppercase all the keys then it doesn't really matter whether it is a multi-valued map or not. You just need to iterate over it.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment on Ernest's correct answer, here's how I might implement the `remove`-and-`put` solution:

```
for (String key : new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet())) {
    String upper = key.toUpperCase();
    for (String value : map.remove(key))
        map.add(upper, value);
}
```

Comment: This seems to have an issue if there are multi values that have differnt case, like:  color=red&Color=blue the second key gets lost

Comment: @Bill Okay, I've adapted my answer based on the only `MultivaluedMap` I know about, which is [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html).

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to put each modified key/value pair into a new map as you processed it. At the end you could either return the new map, discarding the original, or you could `clear()` the original and copy all the elements from the temporary map back into the original. There's not going to be any better way to do it than that.

Comment: +1 You could also do a `remove`-and-`put` in a loop, looping through a _copy_ of the original keys so you avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException`.